# Vbscript to search for all files with an extension and save them to a CSV

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to write a script that will search say C:\ and all of its sub folders for a specific extension and save all of theme to a CSV file. I have tried this but to no avail:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "C:\"

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Wscript.Echo objFolder.GetExtensionName("*.txt")

Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

For Each objFile in colFiles
If objFile.Extension = "pfx" Then
    Wscript.Echo objFile.Name
    End If
Next
Wscript.Echo

ShowSubfolders objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder)
    For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders
        Wscript.Echo Subfolder.Path
        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Subfolder.Path)
        Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
        For Each objFile in colFiles
            Wscript.Echo objFile.Name
        Next
        Wscript.Echo
        ShowSubFolders Subfolder
    Next

Set WScript = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

End Sub
```

I don't think I am going down the right path here. I am not proficient in the least in vb script it just happens to be the only thing I am allowed to use.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Option Explicit 'force all variables to be declared

Const ForWriting = 2
Dim objFSO
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim objTS 'Text Stream Object
Set objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Output.txt", ForWriting, True)

Recurse objFSO.GetFolder("C:\")
objTS.Close()

Sub Recurse(objFolder)
    Dim objFile, objSubFolder

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name)) = "pfx" Then
            objTS.WriteLine(objfile.Path)
        End If
    Next

    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
        Recurse objSubFolder
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is somewhat late, but that's the hard way to get that list.  easiest is to sue the command line:

first identify the file where you want the directories like this:

```
set FileList="C:\path\path\file.csv"
```

Second identify the starting directory like this:

```
set Start="C:\path\path"
```

Then fill it like this:

```
for /F "usebackq" %i in (`dir /s/b "%Start%\*.pfx"`) do echo %~pi>>%filelist%
```

Done and done interactively.

PS - the post took out the backticks.  That's the character usually under the tilde and they should enclose the complete directory command.  Assuming a replace of ! for the backtick tick, the drectory command shold be `!dir/s/b "%Start%\*.pfx"!`

Comment: <pre>Very cool.  I didn't even know you could do things like this.  Just a heads up, though, for people who use this to get started (advanced users probably already know this): when setting your start variable, you will need to end the string with a backslash  
set start="C:\path\path\"  
Otherwise, you'll get a "file not found" because the path and search terms are concatenated together like "C:\path\path*.pfx".  
Also, the modifier "%~pi" will only be writing the path to the file.  "%~fi" writes the entire qualified path.  Check "for /?" in cmd for more help.  
Thank you!</pre>

Comment: Well... that's the first and last time I try to use HTML in my comments.  Ignore the pre tags in my previous comment.  By the time I realized my goof, my 5 minute was up.

Answer (score 1):

Later still but even simpler (and fast :0)):

Open a CMD, CD to the directory in question

**DIR /S /A-D /B C:\*.something >> D:\ListOf.Files**